# Make automatic formatting rule apply only to my calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

On my Outlook 2007 calendar, I view multiple calendars in overlay mode.  For example, I can see my boss's calendar overlaid on my own.

I also have some automatic formatting (Edit > Automatic Formatting) rules set up to highlight certain calendar entries.  For example, meetings I need to attend stand out in a nice bright yellow.

I don't want the automatic formatting to apply to the other calendars.  I can't seem to find any field that I can filter on to limit the rule to just my calendar.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to apply equally well to Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately checked that the `From` or `To` field included me.  That works pretty well.  Meetings/appointments/reminders that I added for myself have the `From` field set to me.  Meetings that I accepted from others have to `To` field including me.  This rule also includes meetings on my boss's calendar that include both of us, but that's actually sort of useful.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer seems to be "you can't". The long answer seems to be "you can't, unless you can find a field under Automatic Formatting|Advanced|Field|All Appointment Fields that you can use to distinguish your calendar from your boss', but most of those would require luck, bodging or both" e.g. if he has a different version of Outlook to you, or you can get at the Outlook Datafile name

Comment: Outlook Datafile name was a good idea.  Unfortunately it shows up blank on all the calendars I checked.